# What is the difference in these URI parameter handler solutions in Vaadin?

Tags: jakarta-ee, uri, vaadin, url-parameters

I've started a new project with Vaadin (6.8.8 version) and I need to show different views depending on the URL.

Suppose that my app shows information about countries (for example). If I access *myapp.com/* I get a form to search whatever country I want, but If I access *myapp.com/34* I get the information view for the country with ID 34.

I did a little search and I found that I can get this functionality with those approaches:

- *MainApplication implements HttpServletRequestListener*
- Setting a *ParameterHandler*
- Setting an *URIHandler*
- Setting an *UriFragmentUtily*

I think I'm a bit lost because I can't see big differences between these approaches.

**What is the best practice to get what I want?** I think *URIHandler* is a good way to do it but I can't say *why*.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a good reason to use Vaadin 6, I recommend you to use Vaadin 7 and take a look at the [Navigator](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.navigator.html) and [RequestHandler](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.requesthandler.html). Vaadin 7 has a lot better URL handling capabilities than its predecessor.

If you have to use Vaadin 6, you could use the [Navigator 7 addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/navigator7%3avaadin)

Comment: I'll use Vaadin 7, but for now I have to use Vaadin 6. Vaadin 7 is a new version, is it completily ready for production?

Comment: Yes, it's new, but it's also stable. Beta and RC versions are well behind now :) I personally have developed an application with Vaadin 7 that is currently in production and there has been no problems so far.